# Web Application Testing Tips

Tags: php, testing, web

I am diving into the web application testing line(php ,ajax,javascript) and need some guidance. There is a lot of stuff in google.

Does anybody known any good links or tutorials to learn from. Any video tutorials that I can watch ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For PHP testing you could check out the [PHPUnit tutorial on the Pear site](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.phpunit.intro.php), and this [video on CakePHP TV](http://tv.cakephp.org/video/CakeFoundation/2011/10/03/phpunit_and_you_-_by_mark_story)

For JS testing it might be worth looking at [Google JS Test](http://code.google.com/p/google-js-test/)

Hope that's useful!

Comment: The video on CakePHP TV link is now broken.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go for automated testing, then I would suggest using [SELENIUM IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/). You should be able to find tutorials & videos to learn how to use it.

Comment: Selenium's documentation section of their website is really great.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth trying a bit of Unit Testing with your PHP. You can take a look at 
http://www.simpletest.org/

Comment: An example of a tutorial using unit testing can be found here http://www.lastcraft.com/first_test_tutorial.php

Answer (score 0):

For PHP testing there's a lot of automated testing framework that you can try out, here's a list of some of them.

- [PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/)

PHPUnit is a programmer-oriented testing framework for PHP.
It is an instance of the xUnit architecture for unit testing frameworks.

Documentation for PHPUnit : https://phpunit.de/documentation.html

---

- [Codeception](http://codeception.com/)

Codeception collects and shares best practices and solutions for testing PHP web applications. With a flexible set of included modules tests are easy to write, easy to use and easy to maintain. Codeception encourages developers and QA engineers to concentrate on testing and not on building test suite.

Documentation for Codeception : http://codeception.com/docs/01-Introduction

---

- [Phpspec](http://www.phpspec.net/en/stable/)

A php toolset to drive emergent
design by specification.

Documentation for Phpspec : http://www.phpspec.net/en/stable/manual/introduction.html

---

- [Peridot PHP](http://peridot-php.github.io/)

highly extensible, highly enjoyable, BDD testing framework for PHP.

Documentation for Peridot PHP : http://peridot-php.github.io/docs/

---

- [Atoum](http://atoum.org/)

atoum is a simple, modern and intuitive unit testing framework for PHP! It is completely standalone, everything is available and works out of the box.

Documentation for Atoum : http://docs.atoum.org/en/latest/

---

these are few of many many other php unit testing frameworks, you can check them all and choose for your self which one to use and which one is best for the job.

Answer (score -3):

Try out for

http://www.w3schools.com/

it will be helpful